# Running a for loop through a tree structure

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium - Python and I'm running a for loop through a tree like structure

It looks like this:

[image]

The id keeps changing in the files but ultimately I want to download the files.

I tried something like this:

```
for id in range(2, 41):
     my_id = "stree{}".format(id)
     browser.find_element_by_id(my_id).click()
     browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

But the for loop shows up a STALEELEMENT in two iterations because in the end of the code I go back.

How do I do it?

Comment: If you can tell exactly on which iteration the `staleElement` occurs then for that, handle it separately, ideally by using an if clause.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: @belwood yes accepted. could you possibly answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same issue I've encounterd twice before, the click() expands the structure somehow making elements below go stale (I don't know why).  You can try the approach below.

The concept is to open the whole structure in the browser first then iterate it afterward. Basically running find_elements on each iteration after the click() so that the list is refreshed.

Pseudo-code (this is breadth-first, but depth-first works too)

```
for each level:
   grab the whole list of elements using find_elements(...)
   for i in 0 to number of elements in the list
      grab the list again (yes the whole list)
      iterate to the ith element and click() it [if it's clickable]
```

Doing find_elements in each loop iteration retrieves valid, visible elements guaranteeing none are stale. After the structure is entirely open, it's safely traversible.

Example code:
(tree_items is the xpath of the elements in the stree object)

```py
# save the names of the target level elements
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(tree_items)
names = []
for elem in elements:
   names.append(elem.text)

# click elements in the target level (names)
for i in range(0, len(elements)):
   elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(tree_items)
   elem = elements[i]
   # only click the elements in the names list (this level)
   if elem.text in names:
      names.remove(elem.text)
      try:
         elem.click()
      except WebDriverException:
         pass # ignore if elem is not clickable
```

After the whole tree is open, use your find_element code to get to the filename to download.

Comment: could you give me some idea on how to write it in python?

Comment: There are multiple stree ids, which should be in the xpath?

Comment: one more doubt: doesn't python run the last for loop? If so, then how will it detect the for loop in your answer?

Comment: The starting point is to find a css selector or xpath that will return a LIST of the elements using find_elements_by_...  One last example.  Let's assume the folders were <LI> elements of a <UL> inside a <DIV> and each folder contains one or more filenames. Using driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li") would return the LIST of folders.  Then using the above algorithm, each folder would be opened making its filenames VISIBLE to selenium.  Once visible, find_elements_by_id(...) for each filename (assuming you know the names already) should work.

Comment: thanks, it works. Just one thing - my code for find_elements_by_id: involves another for loop but if I write another for loop after this then the above code won't execute.

Comment: I'm unable to answer without seeing the relevant code and the page in question.  I suggest using a site like https://codeshare.io/ to share your code and post the link here instead of adding more and more stuff to this question.